# Find smallest number and its index

Tags: python, list, indexing, min

```
l = [0,1,2,0,3]
```

I want to find l's smallest number and its index, which should give

```
(0,0),(0,3)
```

What I have done is

```
def find_smallest(xy):
    return (np.min(xy), xy.index(min(xy)))

find_smallest([0,1,2,0,3])
```

which gives (0,0)

Comment: Something like `np.where(l == np.min(xy))` provided `l` is a numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def find_smallest(xy):
    minimum=np.min(xy)
    index=0
    indexes=[]
    minimums=[]
    for item in xy:
        if item==minimum:
            minimums.append(minimum)
            indexes.append(index)
        index+=1
    return tuple(minimums),tuple(indexes)

find_smallest([0,1,2,0,3])
```

This one should work

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
l = [0,1,2,0,3]

def find_smallest(xy):
    smallest = min(xy)
    return [(j, i) for i, j in enumerate(xy) if j==smallest]

find_smallest(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning the first match, you should build up a list as you iterate over the first list.

```
def find_smallest(xy):
    m = None
    matches = []
    for i, n in enumerate(xy):
        if n == m:
            matches.append((n, i))
        if m is None or n < m:
            m = n
            matches = [(n, i)]
    return matches

print(find_smallest([0,1,2,0,3]))  # [(0, 0), (0, 3)]
print(find_smallest([6,0,1,2,0,3]))  # [(0, 1), (0, 4)]
```

Comment: @SurrealDreams Thanks, but this does work. There was a typo on line #8 where it should have been `m = n` instead of `m = i` but I have just fixed that.

Comment: It does work with your edit.  It took me a minute to see how this works, because it immediately starts building a list of results before the minimum is known, but every time it finds a smaller value it resets the list of results.  It's an interesting approach, and you only have to iterate the list once.